# Problems with migration from WAS 6.1 to WAS 7.0 cookie is always null

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, migration, struts

I have this problem:

1. I migrate my applications from WAS 6.1 to WAS 7.0 using migration tool in `C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin\migration`
2. The application was running just fine in 6.1 server but when I migrated it there is a problem with one `Cookie` I need for getting the division from the user.
3. After debugging a while I realize that the `Cookie` is getting created but for a reason a don't know the `Cookie` is not getting put into the `HttpServletResponse`, so when I try to retrieve the value for the `Cookie` it says that it is `null`.

Here's the snippet of code used to do this:

```
public static void setDivisionCookie( String div, HttpServletResponse res ){
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(USER_DIVISION_COOKIE_NAME, div);
    cookie.setMaxAge(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    cookie.setPath("/");
    res.addCookie( cookie );
}
```

I have to say that the application is running with Struts (these are the jar's I'm using `struts-1.2.9`, `struts2-core-2.1.8.1`, `struts-taglib-1.3.8`)

Answer (score 0):

Each web application get/put cookies under servlet context path. For example

```
cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
```